# Memory leak sending array from C++ to Java with JNI

Tags: java, c++, memory-leaks, java-native-interface

I'm, having problem in sending a chunk of data of ints that is updating constantly from C++ to Java using JNI. The data is sent correctly to java, but in java or in the JNI there is a memory leak, but i'm actually only coping the data to a new array of ints, So I don't know where the error is.

```
int * intArray = new int [frame_size];

int * getData(){
      return intArray;
 }
```

Here is the JNI Code

```cpp
JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_JNIData_InData_getData
(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{
    Data* dataOut;

    jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
    jfieldID fid = env->GetFieldID(cls, "ptr", "J");
    dataOut = (Data *) env->GetLongField(obj, fid);

    jintArray buffer = env->NewIntArray(frame_size);
    env->SetIntArrayRegion(buffer, 0, frame_size, (const jint *)dataOut->getData());

    env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
    return buffer;
}
```

And in java I just have the following code:

```
void processData(){
   int [] val = getData();
}
```

If I comment `getData()` there is no memory leak. I think i has to do the the pointer of the array in C++, any suggesting?

Comment: Of course it leaks memory.  If you're going to call `new[]` where is your call to `delete[]`?  C++ is not Java.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, you're creating a new int[], but never deleting it.

Try this:

```
int *pIntArray = getData();
env->SetIntArrayRegion(buffer, 0, frame_size, (const jint *) pIntArray );
delete[] pIntArray;
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you've open yourself up for a memory leak if for some reason `SetIntArrayRegion` throws an exception.  Better to use RAII for this.

Comment: Right. Better to use a smart pointer throughout, including with getData().

Comment: For JNI coding, you almost never should use naked pointers, especially for things like this.  Those JNI functions can get flaky, and it is very easy to get memory leaks when creating array fields.

Comment: ok, going to try smart pointers for this, when i do delete [] pIntArray I get an error, I believe it's because I'm updating the array in the main

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie JNI functions do not throw C++ exceptions. However, they can put the JVM thread in an exception state and that should be checked for. So, it would be convenient control-flow-wise in the C++ code to use RAII anyway.